# What is this tefillin minhag?

Tags: minhag, tefilin

In [this article](http://www.knishtachada.com/2014/01/26_15.html) discussing how Rav Eliezer Berland came to Breslov Chassidus, [there is a photo](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-8QILKDOhRjA/Utbmf2HFChI/AAAAAAAAAfk/WRaOX25CxJc/s1600/%D7%91%D7%A8+%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94.jpg) of young Berland prior to his bar mitzvah, wrapped in tallis and tefillin.

I immediately noticed the minhag in which he has wrapped the tefillin, and it struck me as a bit odd. It is not the usual Ashkenazi method around the hand.

I'm not an expert on minhagim, but it seems that the "normal" Ashkenazi way of wrapping the tefillin is the Lithuanian minhag. I read [a post on A Simple Jew](http://asimplejew.blogspot.com/2007/12/reclaiming-more-minhagim.html) about his minhag from Sudiklov and the hand wrapping [looks just like](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_7tLqMOXSPm8/R2hskLtv6SI/AAAAAAAACCE/qxgyf-0kFwY/s1600-h/sudtefilin2.JPG) the one in the photo of Berland. (Of course, Berland's tefillin are clearly wrapped inwards per Ashkenazi custom whereas A Simple Jew's are Chassidic and therefore wrap outwards.)

What is the origin of this tefillin wrapping? I have added a photo for convenience. I suspect the minhag might be from Ukraine since Sudiklov (as mentioned in the A Simple Jew blog) is a Ukranian village. Plus, maybe I'm making an assumption that [the way R' Moshe Feinstein ztz''l wraps his tefillin](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Reb_Moshe_Feinstein.jpg) is the way all Ashkenazim do.

[image: Rabbi Eliezer Berland, tefillin bar mitzvah]

Comment: Huh. That’s exactly how I wrap my Tefillin on my hand. Based on that fact alone I suspect this is a Polish minhag.

Comment: @DonielF - Cool.

Comment: @DonielF My family is of Polish origin and doesn't do it like that.

Comment: @Scimonster Nor does mine do as he does around the Bayis. Presumably not every city had exactly the same method. Of course, this entire discussion presupposes that this indeed is Nusach Polin.

Comment: @DonielF - It's so interesting to know that this is minag Polin...I would have thought that it would be minhag Lita.

Comment: Won't comment about the Tefillin windings, but the Tallis is interesting.  I thought Bochurim of Eastern Europe never wore Tallis before marriage, not to mention the actual Tallis appears scarf-like in style...

Comment: @user4751 I believe that custom in and of itself is Hasidic in nature, and also, many bar mitzvah boys do indeed where a tallis for their bar mitzvah but discontinue the practice until marriage.

Comment: R' Moshe's way of wrapping is not the only Ashkenazi way. I've seen multiple methods in schul (mine is standard Ashkenazi: one wrap below the bayit above the elbow, seven times around the forearm [not required me'ikkar hadin, although nor are most of the kerichot] shin on my hand and three wraps around the middle finger). Variants include wrapping around the ma'abarta (as in Chabad, but inward), forming a dalet on the middle and ring fingers, and some other variants which I don't recall off the top of my head

Comment: @user4751, Ezra is one to something. My father's Jekkisch grandfather died some months before my father's bar-mitzvah and his Litvish grandfather got him his tefillin and a tallis (the same scarf narischkeit) for his bar mitzvah, with the misplaced assumption that he would only wear it the once. My poor father had to wear that tallis until he could get himself a new one in Israel as an undergrad (which I now have and need to get new tzitzit on)

Comment: Is it trying to make a daled and shin on the hand?

Answer (score 5):

[image: Tefilin Diagrams]

[image: Tefilin Diagrams]

[image: Tefilin Diagrams- My minhag highlighted]

These are the images from the N'ta-ay Govriel showing every mihag of wrapping the Tefila Shel Yad.  It actually helped my cousin find the origin of his obscure wrapping.

As pointed out there are missing minhagim of Eidot Mizrach, this video shows the Moroccan custom - At around 6:03 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw0uqOtGIns  And in the Hebrew wikipedia page Maran Ovadia Yosef ztz'l has tefillin like Temanim - [image: Maran Yosef with Tefillin]

Comment: Is there a reason #29 is highlighted? OP's picture looks more like #16.

Comment: This chart is a great find, thanks for sharing!

Comment: 14 Ashkenazi methods but only one Sefardi method? That can't be "every" minhag

Comment: I highlighted my minhag.  I imagine there may be one or two more minhagim, inSefardi world, due to the higher uniformity to the vast Ashkenazi world.

Answer (score 3):

In Nit'e Gavriel, Hilkhot weHalikhot ber mitzwa, pag. 362 , picture 16, this wrapping is attributed to: ashkenaz, Alexander, Amshinow, Gur, and other hasidim in Poland and Lituania

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Shmuel, I hope you enjoy our site. On a side note, your answer would be improved if you added scans or pictures of the diagrams in Nit'ei Gavriel